# Open pdf files in new tab

Tags: php, pdf

Good morning to all. 
I am trying to open a pdf file in a new tab I have succesfully uploaded the pdf in the folder I want and the title of the pdf is in the database of that paricular product. from the "product list" I am using a button and open a modal where there are option of which pdf refering to that product (currently we need to upload 2 but in the future maybe more) we need to open.

This is how I call the modal:

`<a href="#docs<?php echo $row['prod_id'];?>" data-target="#docs<?php echo $row['prod_id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" style="color:#fff;" class="small-box-footer"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate text-blue"></i></a>`

and this is the modal:

```
<div id="docs<?php echo $row['prod_id'];?>" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content" style="height:auto">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Supporting Documents of <?php echo $row['prod_name'];?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="price">Technical Datasheet</label>

               <a href="view_docs.php" data-target="view_docs.php" src="../dist/docs/<?php echo $row['prod_tds'];?>"target="_blank">View TDS</a>

              <div class="col-lg-9">

                </div>  
             </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="price">Material Safety Datasheet</label>
                <a href="view_docs.php" data-target="view_docs.php" src="../dist/docs/<?php echo $row['prod_msds'];?>"target="_blank">View MSDS</a>
                <div class="col-lg-9">

                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

While making this I read I need to call a new php with some headers that I donot know how to work with them and I am getting an error of "Failed to load pdf document".

This is the code on view_docs.php:

```
    <?php session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])):
header('Location:../index.php');
endif;

include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');
$file = 'view'; 




$filename = '$file'; /* Note: Always use .pdf at the end. */

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');


@readfile($file);

?>
```

What I am not getting correct? I believe that there is something wrong in the view_docs.php but i donk know how to make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your missing a few things (like the file extension):

```
//no extension
$file = 'view';  

//this is literally $file and never used again
$filename = '$file'; 

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
//the name of the transfered file is filename.php (not really an issue in this case)
//but is that what you wanted there
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
//still no extension on 'view' so your file is just named view (nothing else)
//no file path either.
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
//and you guessed it still no extension (error suppression hides the file not found error)
@readfile($file);
```

The `$filename` is `$file` literally not the value of the variable because of the use of single quotes. PHP does not do variable interpolation (value replacement) on single quoted strings.  Not that it matters because it's never used again.

The `@` probably shouldn't be there or you would see failed to find the file named `view` with not extension.  You should be seeing some stuff like this

> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for view in C:\Unit\eval\1541064182.php on line 2
>
> Warning: readfile(view): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Unit\eval\1541064182.php on line 3

Except it will have your path and not my path to my Unit testing server.

In other words your readfile call is literately this:

```
 @readfile('view');
```

You can leave the download name as `filename.php` but I don't think that is the intention.

```
$file = 'view.pdf'; 

$pathname = $path.$file;

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pathname));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

readfile($pathname);
```

Obviously you'll have to put in the value for the path, or if its in the same folder then you can ignore that.

Oh and last thing get rid of this thing `?>`  because if you have a line return after that, it may corrupt your file.  I forget if that (specifically just a line return) is an issue for PDF, but any content after the closing tag (or before) will become part of the file data.  The end tag is optional and so why risk it.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance I am kinda new to this... I set an id=view_docs in the link at the modal. and then used this id as $file=view_docs and $path=../dist/docs which is the folder where i stock the uploaded pdf's. But I still cannot open it. I see that in $file you set view.pdf. This should be created in the modal or not?

Comment: `This should be created in the modal or not`  I wouldn't. its preferable that the end user never touches the path because of Directory transversal attacks, if all you need is an ID to fetch the filepath from the DB then just pass the ID.  What's to stop me from showing the contents of any file I choose.  I can take the link to your php file and put anything I want in it and `readfile($pathname);` will happily spit it out for me.

Comment: So the id I set in the modal (id="view_docs") takes the the file path from the src=".." I am doing. And in the view_docs.php I will use that id as the $file correct? Or should I state $file='view_docs.pdf'? I am kinda confused with this..

Comment: I don't know what "modal" is (I mean i know what a modal is) but I assume this has some javascript and what not.  So it depends how that works, by default HTML IDs don't get passed to the servers.  So I would refer to whatever documentation came with that thing.   All I know is your not going to find `view.pdf` by looking for `view` with no extension.

Comment: I mean in the link that is in the modal I set the id as '<a href="view_docs.php" data-target="view_docs.php" src="../dist/docs/<?php echo $row['prod_tds'];?>"id="view_docs" target="_blank">View TDS</a>'. And in the view_docs.php I set $file='view_docs.pdf' but I get the same error. From what I understand the id=view_docs is actually the path with the file name correct? Sorry if my questions are confusing...

Comment: HTML ID's are not submitted to the server by default, as I said above.  Now if you have some Javasciript that does that I have no way to know that.  I suggest going to the URL without the model and getting that to show the PDF first.  Then re-integrate that to whatever it is you are using.

Comment: I m not using javascript on that... I believe my problem is that I cannot pass the file name to the next php (view_docs.php) from the previous and I lack on knowledge on how to do it. Can I set the $file somehow before going to view_docs.php?

Comment: Typically you would pass something in a URL using GET or the query string `view_docs.php?doc=1234` then you look that ID up in the DB and get the path.  If you do `view_docs.php?doc=view.pdf` whats to stop me from changing that to `view_docs.php?doc=whateverIwant.php` and downloading any sorcecode page on your site that I want to?  Because that is a possibility with readfile.   For example if you had a wordpress site I could use put `view_docs.php?doc=../wp-config.php` and download your database credentials.   probably not something you want to happen.

Comment: Which is known as a Directory transversal attack.  So dont use a filename that a user can edit, See the normal links to PHP files are fine because the server executes them but readfile will output the contents of that file, which can then be seen.  I don't know how else to explain it, but with a URL the only thing that gets sent to the server is the URL. and query string (`$_GET`) if you use Javascript you can take the data from the ID tag and POST it to the server with AJAX(although I would use an Iframe probably) but that doesn't happen on it's own.

Comment: I think I understand... Let me work it a little bit and see what will happen... I appreciate your support!

Comment: It worked! I set 'href="view_docs.php?id=<?php echo $row['prod_tds'];?>"' and then used the $_GET['id'] to set the $file! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Sure  No problme

Answer (score 0):

You should insert PDF url in link href
// view_docs.pdf

```
<a href="view_docs.pdf" data-target="view_docs.php" src="../dist/docs/<?php echo $row['prod_tds'];?>"target="_blank">View TDS</a>
```